# What's wrong with my codes? When I enter string then the program is stop working. How can I keep work the program even enter strings

Tags: python-3.x

```
print ("bu program sıcaklığa göre suyun durumunu gösterir")
while True:
   s=input("lütfen sıcaklığı giriniz.çıkmak içn q ya bas")
   if s=="q":
        print("çıkılıyor")
        break
   try:
        s_int=int(s)
   except ValueError:
        print("Lütfen sadece sayı giriniz")
        raise
   if s_int<0:
        print("Durum Buzdur")
   elif s_int>=100:
        print("Durum Buhar")
   else:
        print("Durum su")
```

Comment: Palease sort out the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem that you want to swallow the exception and keep the program running on invalid input? If so, remove the raise. You'll also need to put the s_int checks inside the try.

```
print ("bu program sıcaklığa göre suyun durumunu gösterir")
while True:
   s=input("lütfen sıcaklığı giriniz.çıkmak içn q ya bas")
   if s=="q":
        print("çıkılıyor")
        break
   try:
        s_int=int(s)
        if s_int<0:
            print("Durum Buzdur")
        elif s_int>=100:
            print("Durum Buhar")
        else:
            print("Durum su")
   except ValueError:
        print("Lütfen sadece sayı giriniz")
```